# Reloading 3 DIVs with jQuery in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 3 DIVs in which I load 3 different pages, and then i refresh them with jQuery with this code:

```
var auto_view = setInterval(
    function () {
        $('#viCount').load('adViCount.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 500
);

var auto_like = setInterval(
    function () {
        $('#liCount').load('adLiCount.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 500
);

var auto_favorite = setInterval(
    function () {
        $('#faCount').load('adFaCount.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 500
);
```

To show:

```
<div id="viCount"></div>
<div id="liCount"></div>
<div id="faCount"></div>
```

- I would like to know if this way is correct
- I would like to set the value when page loads, then reload div every 10 seconds
- I would like to know if this won't cause a high server load (performance)

Thank you guys

Comment: What do you mean by server load? Performing a POST/GET request?

Comment: `I would like to set the value when page load`: which value?

Comment: `then reload div after 10 seconds`: reload once after 10 seconds or every 10 secons?

Comment: High server load my be caused by sending requests too often.

Comment: @Simon the current value for exemple (current likes) what i see here, when page loads, it waits until 10 seconds then i can see the numbers

Comment: @Simdine Check if my answer is what you wanted.

Comment: Server load: i mean my VPS, 10 seconds for 1000 active users, is that a bad idea ?

Comment: the server load depends on what your php scripts do. so you should keep that at the minimum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your loading stuff in one function, call it on DOM ready and the every 10 seconds:

```
function performRequests() {
    $('#viCount').load('adViCount.php').fadeIn("slow");
    $('#liCount').load('adLiCount.php').fadeIn("slow");
    $('#faCount').load('adFaCount.php').fadeIn("slow");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Load once on pageload
    performRequests();

    // And then every 10 seconds
    var requestsInterval = setInterval(performRequests, 10000);
});
```

Better way would be to return those three views in a single call (e.g. you could return JSON) so you have less server requests.

Comment: This seems good, can you check this priented screen [IMG]http://i59.tinypic.com/243kms7.png[/IMG] do you an idea how to fix that ? it's with IE

Comment: Can you check if it's still happening when **a)** changing `setInterval` to `setTimeout` and **b)** commenting out the `setInterval` line. Just to be sure it's caused by this.

Comment: I used var requestsInterval = setTimeout(performRequests, 10000); instead of var requestsInterval = setInterval(performRequests, 10000); but samething

Comment: What heppens if you delete this line? What is you network tab saying? Is there a neverending call? Give us some more informations.

Comment: if i delete it, nothing works, this is happenning only with IE

Comment: in the same page i have another call "$(document).on('click', '.clickIn', function(){" i deleted this function, it's working, need to cache: false ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Obviously the given answer is not affecting you described error.

Comment: Maybe your AJAX call has option `async` set to false?

Comment: no at all, i cleared the history, i don't see it now, Thanks Simon

Answer (score 0):

To set a value you will need to call a function when load() is completed, e.g.:

```
var foo=1;
$('#faCount').load('adFaCount.php', function(){
  foo++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

to fill the values during the load of the page you should include the script in php (sorry, i dont know how to do it)

to reload the scripts every 10 secs you can set the interval to 10000.

to stop the reloading you can use the `clearInterval` function

```
clearInterval(auto_view);
```

well, i dont know if that's the **best** way to do it, but if you need to refresh the divs every 10 secs that shoud be my way to do it.